# How do i delete unknown addresses from a group

Tags: contacts

I am generating a list to send a mailing to via postal mail. I have created the group and now need to delete contacts from the group who don't have an address.

Answer (score 4):

You can use use Search Builder (Search > Search Builder) to search for contacts in a group and add another search field like contact City (Primary or whichever address field you are using) is empty.

You can then select the results and delete, or remove from the group.